# Foreign key with additional constraints?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-key, constraint, check-constraints

There is a table called `Item(id, name, cost)` and `Orders(id, bill_id, item_id, units)`, which is created to track orders placed, where same *bill_id* means it belongs to a single order.

How to impose an additional constraint in DB that says *Item* should be "Available" (at that point of time) if it needs be to added as *item_id* in the *Order* table? An item is manually determined as "Available" and can't be derived from other fields in the database in this scenario.

One schema design (I prefer) is to add a *Type* column which would have "Available" and "Unavailable" fields. But how can I check the Foreign Key constraint *item_id* should not only be a Primary Key in `Item` table, its *Type* should be "Available" as well?

This [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135754/how-to-make-a-foreign-key-with-a-constraint-on-the-referenced-table-in-postgresq) using *check constraints* seems close, but is that the only way? I feel this is a trivial thing for RDBMS, or is this is not a normalized data?

The other schema design (I don't prefer) is to have a Table called "Menu" which could have *only* the *Items* Available. The problem is that this table is going to very dynamic in nature and it keeps changing depending on the availability of items. And, I am just creating a subset table out of Items depending on its state which doesn't seem to be a nice idea.

It's easy to do this programmatically; however, how do I achieve this in RDBMS? I like the idea of Database being intelligent enough to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Original answer is wrong!** See *Edit 1* for the corrected version.

---

### Original answer

An amazing solution would require a foreign key to a column in a view or a inherited table, but unfortunately PostgreSQL (I suppose that's your RDBMS because of the tag) does not have that (yet).

I think a simple change in the way you organize the data would suffice: create a table like *ItemsAvailableQuantity*, connecting an *Item* with its availability which will be references in the orders. When an item is not available anymore, `DELETE` it from it.

```
CREATE TABLE Item (
    id   serial  NOT NULL
  , name text    NOT NULL
  , cost numeric

  , PRIMARY KEY (id)
  , CONSTRAINT positive_cost
        CHECK (cost > 0)
    );

CREATE TABLE ItemAvailableQuantity (
    id       serial  NOT NULL
  , item_id  integer NOT NULL
  , quantity integer NOT NULL

  , PRIMARY KEY (id)
  , FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
        REFERENCES Item (id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
  , CONSTRAINT postive_quantity -- This constraint is the same as
        CHECK (quantity > 0)    -- checking something like `available = TRUE`.
    );

CREATE TABLE ItemOrder (       -- Changed the name from `Order` because
    id      serial  NOT NULL   -- PostgreSQL refuses that name, somehow
  , bill_id integer NOT NULL
  , item_id integer NOT NULL
  , units   integer NOT NULL

  , PRIMARY KEY (id)
  , FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
        REFERENCES ItemAvailableQuantity (id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
-- Uncomment when `Bill` table is ready
--  , FOREIGN KEY (bill_id)
--        REFERENCES Bill (id)
--        ON UPDATE CASCADE
--        ON DELETE CASCADE
  , CONSTRAINT positive_units
        CHECK (units > 0)
    );
```

**Notice!** The constraint *positive_units* may cause problems when your software reduces the units and reaches 0. Make it something like `CHECK >= 0` if needed, or add a trigger that automatically `DELETE`-s rows when *units* reaches 0 (or less) on each `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. This would preserve the table *ItemAvailableQuantity* to have only actually available items, which is what we want for being referenced from the table *ItemOrder*.

This should solve your problem. It's not an exact answer to your question. That would involve a trigger or a `CHECK` calling a function as in the link you provided.

To easily see the quantity of the items then, just create a view that joins *ItemAvailableQuantity* and *Item*. If you really want then, make it `INSERT`-able [with a trigger (see yellow-box warning)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-update.html).

---

### Edit 1

Actually *Order* (a.k.a. *ItemOrder*) should reference the *Item* instead of *ItemAvailableQuantity* to avoid any problem when the *Item* is not currently available, as stated in the comment.

This suggest we should remove the whole table *ItemAvailableQuantity* and only add a column *available_quantity* on *Item*.

```
CREATE TABLE Item (
    id                 serial NOT NULL
  , name               text   NOT NULL
  , cost               numeric
  , available_quantity integer NOT NULL

  , PRIMARY KEY (id)
  , CONSTRAINT positive_cost
        CHECK (cost > 0)
  , CONSTRAINT non_negative_quantity
        CHECK (quantity >= 0)
    );
```

Then, to be certain of inserting only available items into orders we could just run

```
INSERT INTO ItemOrder (bill_id, item_id, units) VALUES
    (SELECT id FROM Bill WHERE condition = something -- customize at will
    , SELECT id FROM Item WHERE available_quantity >= wanted_quantity
        AND other_condition = something
    , wanted_quantity)
    ;
```

where `wanted_quantity` is a parameter passed by your software to the query.

Still, solves the problem, but is no direct answer to the question.

Comment: Isn't this a bit like the second schema solution I suggested? How can I delete rows in ItemAvailableQuantity if I am referencing them from Orders as Foreign Key? Won't that also mean several ItemAvailableQuanity IDN's might refer to the same Item since the old one gets deleted and we need new entry when its re-stocked? If you are not deleting it then you actually end you with the same problem that "Available" has in terms of checking another column along with Foreign Key. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Yes, it actually is. I have misintrepreted your suggestion about the _Menu_ table.

I edited the answer about the rest. Hope it's clearer now.